# Can a Git repo act as a child/inherit from another Git repo?

Tags: git, github

Git newbie question...

I have a situation where I want to distribute metadata in a hub-n-spoke model to multiple software deployments.  For example, deployments 'A', 'B', 'C' should all receive metadata that is common to all three.  The plan is to setup the common metadata in a central git repo (aka 'common' repo)

However, the local deployments can also create their own metadata.  Hence,  deployment 'C' can add new stuff to extend what it gets from the hub-n-spoke common repo.

is there a way in Git to setup each hub to have their own git repo that will extend the common repo?  I've read something about sub modules Does that address this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the answer to your question is that you should really use submodules (if I get you right). So you will have:

- Common repository:

  - Submodule repository A
  - Submodule repository B
  - Submodule repository C

[Here](https://github.com/githubtraining/example-dependency) you can see a simple repository with one submodule.

[Working with submodules](https://github.blog/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules).

Comment: If you take 'A' as an example,  would the 'common' repo be a sub module of repo 'A'?

Comment: @user2868835: No, in this setup, the common repo would be the superproject. The sub-repositories have no idea that they *are* subrepositories, and can be cloned without the superproject existing at all. The superproject is aware that the submodules exist, though. So you might want to invert the structure—but if you do, you'll have multiple clones of the common submodule (takes more disk space, but works).

Comment: @user2868835, **torek** is right. In my hierarchy you have 4 separate repositories - A, B, C are submodules of the "Common" repository.

Answer (score 0):

Your model can be achieved with branching.

Step 1: You create a main or root branch and populate it with your configuration files.
Step 2: Sub-projects create a branch off of root, and begin editing files as they choose.

...

Step N: To update a child's metadata data, the child project simply pulls updates from the root branch and merges as needed. The child project would fully inherit all changes from the parent with full freedom to diverge as it chooses (at the maintainers discretion).

This can be augmented with [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), where the project consuming the configuration data creates a submodule that is a fork of the original root branch.